# Content is not loading because its MIME type, "text/html" is not "text/css"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, mern

I tried to deploy my MERN application on Heroku, but when tried to run "heroku local" localhost 5000 showed an empty page and the console show the following errors. These are the errors:

[image: These are the errors.]

I've already tried so many solutions but none of them worked.

This is the package.json file from the node application:

```js
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^5.3.3",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.13.7",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "react-router": "^5.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.16"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build":"cd client && npm run build",
    "install-client":"cd client && npm install",
    "start": "nodemon app.js",
    "heroku-postbuild":"cd client && npm run install-client && npm run build"
    
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

This is the code snippet added to the server.js

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));
    }
    
 app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
});
```

And this is the package.json from the react application

```js
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "history": "^5.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router": "^5.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It appears an HTML page (probably your default page - index.html) is being returned rather than the actual resource your are requesting. This is caused by a server configuration error in which the default HTML page is returned in place of assets that are not found or reachable on the server.

Comment: @RandyCasburn , sir, where do I have to change? Or is there anything to add to the server.js?

Comment: Start by looking into your config: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem might be `server.js` file cannot access properly `build` folder of the `frontend/client`. Can you delete all of this:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));
    }
    
 app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
});
```

And add this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client/build')));
```

I assume your `client` folder and `server.js` file are at the same level, that's why it is `./client...` If not, define path route accordingly. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: I replaced the "if" condition with the above line and that worked. Thank you.